# Paypal REST api payments endpoint always yields 401

Tags: rest, paypal

```
curl -v --insecure -H "Authorization: Bearer A0154m48uAapcL0HYC1n.8kWdiQzwHIeh0qC3h66P2QGK0s" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment

< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
* Server Apache-Coyote/1.1 is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< PROXY_SERVER_INFO: host=slcjavapapi3029b.slc.paypal.com;threadId=39967
< Paypal-Debug-Id: b182cbfc9dd59
< CORRELATION-ID: b182cbfc9dd59
< Content-Language: *
< Date: Wed, 15 Jul 2015 22:16:05 GMT
< Content-Type: text/xml
< Content-Length: 0
```

Even though other endpoints work just fine, such as

```
curl -v --insecure -H "Authorization: Bearer A0154m48uAapcL0HYC1n.8kWdiQzwHIeh0qC3h66P2QGK0s" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://api.paypal.com/v1/identity/openidconnect/userinfo/?schema=openid

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 15 Jul 2015 22:19:59 GMT
* Server Apache-Coyote/1.1 is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Paypal-Debug-Id: b93fbda0effed
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 107
< Set-Cookie: Apache=10.73.8.97.1436998799550367; path=/; expires=Fri, 07-Jul-45 22:19:59 GMT
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

Other endpoints work fine as well. It seems the payments listing always returns 401.

Answer (score 0):

When you go live with your application to process direct credit card payments, you will need to make sure you are approved for live direct credit card payments.

A quick way to check is to log in at the [Developer Site](http://developer.paypal.com) > go to My Account > under Live, click Enable next to Direct Credit Card.

Make sure you are using your Live Client ID and Secret.
[Go Live With PayPal Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/goingLive/)